# How to handle corner-cases of a wrap-around grid?

Tags: algorithm

I want to use an 'endless' grid where independently moving points passing the left-side re-enters the grid on the right-side, and vice versa, same for top/bottom. My problem is how to handle the corner-cases.

Ideas I have:
1. make the grid rectangular and assume the corners to belong to the longer side, but I have difficulty with a cluster of points that covers to both sides of a corner;
2. make the grid-sides dynamically variable in length and pick a wrap-around side when needed so that wrap-around will always be either L-R or T-B
3. a mix of the above, but the wrap-around is to the diagonally opposing corner and side, e.g.: assume the point leaves TL-corner, then it re-enters BR-corner. But this again will fail to handle a cluster of points - the points moves independently, but apparent proximity must be retained.

Any ideas/ use-cases on how to handle this? (Is it even possible?)

Comment: You list possible solutions, but I don't see any corner cases here. Technically, what you describe at the top is the surface of a torus. Just let, say, `x in [0..w)` and `y in [0..h)`. Any time `x` and `y` change, take the remainder modulo `w` and `h`, respectively.

Comment: @Gassa: I had to go look up how to handle the modulus of negative numbers & learned something, thx :) This may be the answer, I'll have to test it.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with moving a point to a diagonally opposite corner? That is, if a point enters *exactly* a corner, then move it to a diagonally opposite. If a point does not enter *exactly* a corner, but a side close to a corner, then wrap only around that side, and if a point then enters another side (as will usually be if a point was moving towards a corner but missed a corner a bit), then wrap it too.

Example for two points moving in top-left direction:

```
+------+    +------+    +------+    +------+
|      |    |*o    |    |      |    |      |
| *o   |    |      |    |      |    |      |
|      | -> |      | -> |      | -> |    *o|
|      |    |      |    |o    *|    |      |
+------+    +------+    +------+    +------+
```

Of course, you should not be worried about seeming separation of points at the third picture. Your sides are wrapped, so the points are still in neighbor cells.